# Run multiple commands on processbuilder in same session of sub process

Tags: java

I am trying to run unix commands using java Processbuilder. It creates sub processes each time new command is given. How can i run all commands in same session ?
 I am trying to implement 
1. & - puts job in background
2. Fg (id) brings job in foreground
3. Jobs - display current background processes in same terminal.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Job-control commands like `fg` and `jobs` are typically implemented as shell built-ins. Since it sounds like you're trying to build a shell, you will likely need to implement this functionality in you shell instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to run command simultaneously is put all command in one scrip file an and then run that script file using `Processbuilder`

You can pass parameters as well.

```
$ cat myscript
#!/bin/bash
echo "First arg: $1"
echo "Second arg: $2"
$ ./myscript hello world
First arg: hello
Second arg: world
```

Comment: I need to take input from user and then run them. User will enter commands one by one. Will script file work still ?

Comment: Note that job-control commands like `fg` and `jobs` probably won't work like you expect if you run them from a script.